# Newbie C# Question about float/int/text type formatting

Tags: c#, types, floating-point, integer

I'm a total C# newb with a light (first year CS) background in Python. I wrote a console program in Python for doing marathon pace running calculations and I'm trying to figure out the syntax for this in C# using Visual Studio 2010. Here's a chunk of what I've got so far:

```
string total_seconds = ((float.Parse(textBox_Hours.Text) * 60 * 60) + (float.Parse(textBox_Minutes.Text) * 60) + float.Parse(textBox_Seconds.Text)).ToString();

float secs_per_unit = ((float)(total_seconds) / (float)(textBox_Distance.Text));
float mins_per_unit = (secs_per_unit / 60);

string pace_mins = (int)mins_per_unit.ToString();
string pace_secs = (float.Parse(mins_per_unit) - int.Parse(mins_per_unit) * 60).ToString();


textBox_Final_Mins.Text = pace_mins;
textBox_Final_Secs.Text = pace_mins;
```

Imagine you have a running pace of 8 minutes and 30 seconds per mile. secs_per_unit would be 510, mins_per_unit would be 8.5. pace_mins would simply be 8 and pace_secs would be 30. In Python I'd just convert variables from a float to a string to get 8 instead of 8.5, for example; hopefully the rest of the code gives you an idea of what I've been doing.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be better if you just specify what you are getting now in textBox_final_Mins and textBox_Final_Secs. And, what you want there

Answer (score 2):

For float to string if you want to cut off the fraction

```
.ToString("F0")
```

It would be better if you rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hours and minutes should only take integers as you're already taking seconds (doesn't make sense to have have 1.5 hours and 30 minutes instead of just 2 hours 0 minutes).

```
var numHours = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Hours.Text);
var numMinutes = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_Minutes.Text);
var numSeconds = Convert.ToDouble(textBox_Seconds.Text);

var totalDistance = Convert.ToDouble(textBox_Distance.Text);

var totalSeconds = ((numHours)*60) + numMinutes)*60 + numSeconds;

var secsPerUnit = totalSeconds/totalDistance;
var minsPerUnit = secsPerUnit/60;

var paceMinsStr = Math.Floor(minsPerUnit).ToString();

var paceSeconds = minsPerUnit - Math.Floor(minsPerUnit);
var paceSecondsStr = (paceSeconds/ 100 * 60).ToString();
```

Written quickly, haven't tested it.. but something like this should work, at least with very minor tweaks/typo fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Overall, store things as integers more, rather than storing as floats and converting to integers multiple times. And don't convert to a string until the last moment.

```
// I'm assuming that the text boxes aren't intended to hold a fraction, 
// "8.5", for example. Therefore, use 'int' instead of 'float', and don't 
// convert to a string at the end.
int total_seconds = int.Parse(textBox_Hours.Text) * 60 * 60 + 
                    int.Parse(textBox_Minutes.Text) * 60 + 
                    int.Parse(textBox_Seconds.Text);

// you missed a Parse here.
// Use two separate variables for seconds per unit: 
// one for the total (510, in your example), one for just the seconds 
// portion of the Minute:Second display (30).
int total_secs_per_unit = (int)(total_seconds / float.Parse(textBox_Distance.Text));

int mins_per_unit = total_secs_per_unit / 60;
int secs_per_unit = total_secs_per_unit % 60;

string pace_mins = mins_per_unit.ToString();
string pace_secs = secs_per_unit.ToString();

textBox_Final_Mins.Text = pace_mins;
textBox_Final_Secs.Text = pace_secs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [cast operators and conversion functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

This would be a cast:

```
double d = 1.2;
int i = (int)d;
```

This would be a conversion:

```
string s = "1";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
```